# How to use useLocation hook of React Router DOM v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<div
  className={`alert alert-${showAlert?.color} alert-fixed fade ${
    showAlert ? "show" : "d-none"
  }`}
  role="alert"
  style={{
    width: "450px",
    right: "1%",
    top: "15%",
    bottom: "unset",
    left: "unset",
    transform: "unset",
  }}
>
  <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <strong>{showAlert?.msg}!</strong>
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn-close"
      onClick={() => setShowAlert(false)}
    ></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Step 1 might be _calling it_ somewhere, but we can't even see if what you've posted is a function-based component. Maybe start with the documentation (React Router's, but also the [tour] and [ask]).

Comment: Not sure what your question is - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

First you have to import the useLocation hook

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

then set

```
const location = useLocation();
```

now you can use the location object which has the following properties:
key, pathname, search, hash, state

```
{
  key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  search: '?some=search-string',
  hash: '#howdy',
  state: undefined
}
```

Here's another demo screenshot to what location object looks like:

[image: console.log of 'location' object]

Answer (score 0):

You can import the useLocation hook into your project using

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

If you want to read about it you can use this article:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-router-hooks/